# Why does scanner work to create an array?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I wrote a small program that checks if strings are sorted in alphabetical order from user input on one line separated by whitespace. It works and that's great, but what I don't understand is why I can use scanner to create the array when the size has not been set. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] stringArray = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        boolean alphabetical = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            if (stringArray[i].compareTo(stringArray[i - 1]) < 0) {
                alphabetical = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(alphabetical);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear about what size are you talking about.

Comment: The size of the array.

Comment: "_why I can use scanner to create the array when the size has not been set_" - it is not the `Scanner` doing that here. It is actually the [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method called on the `String` returned by `nextLine()`, which returns the array. You don't have to specify a size, since the `split()` method is returning the array _for you_, therefore you don't need to create any array yourself (including not to worry about what size it might have)

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense now!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to be found in this method: `.split(" ");`.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):
**split**
`public String[] split(String regex)`
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
[...]
**Returns:**
the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression